# How to use the javascript call method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-call, method-call

Is it possible to use the `call method` of javascript (as described in the [mdn documentation])
in order to pass the argument `this`?

Having for example this code:

```
console.log(this);
$('#image_id').load(function () {
    console.log(this);
});
```

I want that the second `this` (the one included in the `load function`) refers to the same as the first one.

I've tried with

```
console.log(this);
$('#image_id').load.call(this, function () {
    console.log(this);
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank you all in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not like that, because you're not calling the callback. It's being called internally.

You could use `.bind` though.

```
console.log(this);
$('#image_id').load( function () {
    console.log(this);
}.bind(this));
```

But it isn't available in older browsers. *(This is native `.bind()`, not jQuery's.)*

---

jQuery has something that will work called `$.proxy`...

```
console.log(this);
$('#image_id').load($.proxy(function () {
    console.log(this);
},this));
```

...where the first argument is your function, and the second argument is the value you want to use for `this` in the callback.

Comment: Thank you they both work perfectly!  
So do you think that the second one will work even with older browsers?

Just a note: in the second one you forgot a point after load
It might be $('#image_id').load($.proxy(function () {

Comment: Your second solution works great in all cases I tested, even with old browsers, tablets and heavy codes. Not the same for the `bind` one .. maybe because it's too recent.

Comment: @LucaBorrione: Yeah, the native `.bind` won't work in older browsers, but jQuery's `$.proxy` is designed to work in those older ones. Thanks for the heads up on the stray `.`. I'll remove it. :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `call` (or `apply`)

You should do this instead:

```
var that = this;
console.log(this);
$('#image_id').load( function () { 
    console.log(that); 
});
```

Javascript has lexical scoping, which means that the variable `that` is available to your callback, and has the value of where it is defined.  In this case, `that` is defined to be `this` in the outer scope.

Comment: I knew about that, I should have mentioned it.
I was searching a way to use `this` inside the `load function`, as bind does. I should clarify it better. Thank you anyway for your point, at least it always works great in any situation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can `.call` jQuerys function with whatever, but that only affects that function. The function you pass is a separate callback function with `this` controlled by jQuery.

You can use `$.proxy` to force a context of the callback.

```
$('#image_id').bind( "load", $.proxy( console.log, console, this ) );
```

If you wish to do more than logging it becomes more ugly:

```
$('#image_id').bind( "load", $.proxy( function(){
     console.log( this );
     alert( this );
}, this ) );
```

Comment: Your first example is very interesting too, thank you.
Basically your answer is the same of `am not i am`'s one, I checked that one only because I found his first solution clearer. But this is just my own taste. Thanks again

Comment: @LucaBorrione basically you can just directly pass a bound console log instead of having to make a wrapper function that just calls console.log. But this only works if you just wanna call one function in the handler :P

Comment: I'm not sure if I caught you, anyhow my function was only an example of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
var self = this;
$('#image_id').load(function(){
    (function(){
        console.log(this);
    }).call(self);
});
```

Comment: Hello, this is a very interesting solution from the syntax point of view. Just a note: you forgot `.call` after `load` it should be `$('#image_id').load(function(){` ... the weak point is that you need to define `self` outside .. you cannot use `}).call(this);` .. so basically it's the same of using directly `self` inside the `load function` as `hvgotcodes` shows. The solution using `bind` is quicker and easier. Thanks anyhow for pointing it out.

Comment: @Luca Borrione : Thanks for spotting the mistake. About the solution, I agree that using `bind` you have a more clean and readable solution, but you should keep in mind that it is a recent addition to ecmascript, so it might not be available in all browsers(take a look here to see the availability of this functionality : http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). My solution might be better in some scenarios because it doesn't need to change the actual code in the handler; this way you could use the same handler in different contexts without the need to rewrite context references.